# How to use Google Text-To-Speech on Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I had started out doing a games/apps (just make for fun so doesn't have exciting gameplay) where it can read out the word that show on screen. Had tested out  http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%20World , but it doesn't work out so I started a trial on Google Cloud Platform, and now I stuck on how to use its Text-To-Speech function on Unity. Is it possible to use Google TTS on Unity? Cause, when I use using Google.Could.Text-To-Speech.V1 it shows error where it doesn't recognize Google.

Answer (score 1):

The text-to-speech API works by making an HTTP POST request to `https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize`, with the text in the body of the request. I'm not familiar with Unity3d, but a quick check of the documentation shows you can use `UnityWebRequest.Post` to make a HTTP POST request - note that this means your game must be online.

[Check the quickstart guide for more information](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol).
Alternatively, a quick Google search shows there are various plugins/assets available directly for Unity3d which may be better suited.

Comment: Already read through all the documentation by show no sight of Unity. I know there is several plugins I can use, but there is no point as my main purpose making this game is to learn more, no point using plugins. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I needed to use the service myself for my work, here is a short summary of what I found. This [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1/latest) is the one for the Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 module for .NET or put another way C#. Nearly everything I needed can be found there. Here a list of what I did (apart from authentification, which it weirdly worked without) step by step:

1. Install the package from https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity as we need it for step 2 and NuGet (where we get the Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 package from), is normally not playing along with unity well. NuGetForUnity fixes this problem.
2. Import the Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 module via the NuGetForUnity package (see the instructions on their github page)
3. Write the code using the example at [this part of the mentioned documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1/latest#sample-code).
4. Replace the client definition with the REST API variant (see [this part of the docs](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1/latest#using-the-rest-http11-transport)) as it does not work from inside Unity with the normal variant.

I also tried to change the audio format to .ogg, but this did lead to an error, most likely because it uses an encoding different to the one of unity. Mp3s worked fine for me.

I authenticated using a call to `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", <your-jsonCredentialsPath>, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);`
, but as mentioned, this was not needed for some reason. If you need further information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is working as you described, but it asked me authentication, So just need to make sure that google cloud project created properly and enabled cloud text to speech API, must get correct oauth2 credentials under service accounts on Console Cloud Google.